# breeze.js & SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, breeze, sharepoint-2013

I would love to use **breeze.js** to communicate with **SharePoint 2013**.
As we are starting to write apps for SharePoint, i think that breeze.js will be a great tool.

SharePoint uses an [ODATA-Api](http://blog.concentra.co.uk/2013/02/06/odata/), [specs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142385.aspx)

What are the steps i have to take to **get breeze to play nicely with the SharePoint** backend? As far as i know, this has not been done - and i would like to show that this can be done.

[follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310195/from-jquery-ajax-to-breeze-js-sharepoint-odata-example)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a great idea! We have no SharePoint expertise in house. But we'd be happy to help you be successful by answering questions. The place to start ... is trying to query a SharePoint resource yourself using the API you mentioned. Breeze is happy to communicate with OData endpoints. You might begin by reading the [Breeze OData documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/odata).

Comment: Thank you Ward. I enjoyed your talk at .net rocks and i am looking forward for your angular talk. I will start now by learning a bit more about ODATA and the SharePoint-API. I really hope that you can make a pluralsight course about breeze.js soon :)